# warning MSB8012 building fltk.sln for VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, fltk

I have installed the latest version of fltk 1.3.3. I run into build errors every time I want to build the "Demo" project in VS 2015. I have seen the same question for older versions of VS; none of them seem to help me resolve this issue. I've tried to change the debug information format to the other available values but this has not helped.  In fact when I tried to build a release version, avast kicked in and blocked the whole thing.  When it comes to dealing with the $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values, I'm totally out of my depth.  This takes me to Microsoft.CppBuild.targets which is something I don't want to mess with. FLTK is SUCH a pain to do anything with from beginning to end. This is the message I get:

"MSB8012    TargetPath(C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\c++ course files\Visual C++\fltk-1.3.2\ide\VisualC6.\Debug/Demo\Demo.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\c++ course files\Visual C++\fltk-1.3.2\test\Demod.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).  Demo    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets   1189"

If there's anyone out there with some ideas as to how to resolve this, I'd greatly appreciate that. I've spent the whole day trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the target specified by the linker (`C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\c++ course files\Visual C++\fltk-1.3.2\test\Demod.exe`) is different than the target specified by the compiler (`C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\c++ course files\Visual C++\fltk-1.3.2\ide\VisualC6.\Debug/Demo\Demo.exe`).

If you right click on your project > Properties > Configuration Properties > General

Make sure that "Output Directory" and "Target Name" match Configuration Properties > Linker > Output File.

You could make them the same by setting Linker > General > Output File to 
`$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)`

If your Linker's output file is already set to that, then the macros are somehow wrong.

Comment: or you can just go to the "Linker > General > Output File" and select "Inherit from parent or project defaults"

Comment: OK I've tried matching names and/or inherit...the only change I can see is that it continues to report errors in the build but now it doesn't tell you what they are; it just does not build. As AndyG says, there must be something wrong with the macros. How frustrating...

Comment: These are some of the erros I get--
65>cl : Command line error D8016: '/ZI' and '/Gy-' command-line options are incompatible
69>------ Build started: Project: table, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
67>cl : Command line error D8016: '/ZI' and '/Gy-' command-line options are incompatible
68>cl : Command line error D8016: '/ZI' and '/Gy-' command-line options are incompatible
69>cl : Command line error D8016: '/ZI' and '/Gy-' command-line options are incompatible
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 69 failed, 8 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: @PabloVent: `/ZI`and `/Gy` are command-line options that can be [looked up at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx). Examine the docs and make sure that your options are set properly.

Comment: Thanks very much AndyG, I have succeeded in building and debugging fltk.  Thanks very much for your support

Comment: @PabloVent: Great, glad you sorted it out.

Comment: @Pablo Any chance you can write about what you did to get it to work? Because guess what I'm trying to do right now...